# Codility AbsDistinct: Why is this solution not O(n)?

Tags: java, programming-challenge, complexity

This is part of a series of algorithmic lessons and tests by Codility.

For copyright reasons, I cannot reproduce the [question](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoNBBZ3G-2JM/), which asks to compute the number of distinct absolute values in a given sorted array.

The question requires a response in \$O(n)\$ time complexity. My response (below) was detected as \$O(n*log(n))\$ by Codility, but I have no idea why. It looks to me like we're only going to go over each item of the array once. Am I wrong or is this \$O(n)\$?

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int result = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = A.length - 1;

    while (start <= end) {
        result++;
        int startValue = Math.abs(A[start]);
        int endValue = Math.abs(A[end]);
        int currentValueFound = Math.max(startValue, endValue);
        while (start <= end && Math.abs(A[start]) == currentValueFound) {
            start++;
        }
        while (start <= end && Math.abs(A[end]) == currentValueFound) {
            end--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In addition, if anyone has an idea what could have triggered the error in the `arth_overflow` test, I am interested.

Comment: [Perhaps you can't copy/paste from the challenge site, but certainly you could provide us with a summary.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1994/41243) Better reviews happen when people understand what it is your code is supposed to do. And [links can be unreliable](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2015/41243).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why your solution would not be O(*N*).

However, it would fail if the array contained `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, since its absolute value won't fit within an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is provably \$O(n)\$. With each iteration of any of the inner loops you get rid of one value. Therefore their count is upper bounded by \$n\$.

In every iteration of the outer loop, you make at least one iteration of some inner loop. Therefore the count is bounded by \$n\$, too.

---

I guess, Codility does some syntactical analysis and sees the nested loops. Try to convert the inner loops into `if`s (keep the current maximum value across iterations).